# Filter values not equal in pyspark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null

I have a table like the following:

```
+---+----+----+
| id|Sell| Buy|
+---+----+----+
|  A|null|null|
|  B|   Y|   Y|
|  C|null|   Y|
|  D|   Y|null|
|  E|null|null|
+---+----+----+
```

I can easilty filter single or both columns when value equals "Y". For example, the following filters when both columns are "Y":

```
df.filter((df["Buy"] == "Y") & (df["Sell"] == "Y"))
```

However, how can I filter for when a single column or both columns do not equal "Y"?? What is the code for each case? I have tried these codes, and they return no rows:

```
df.filter((df["Buy"] != "Y") & (df["Sell"] != "Y"))
df.filter(~((df["Buy"] == "Y") | (df["Sell"] == "Y")))
```

It seems it does not capture null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that they are null, null values are somehow special

Try this to filter for values where `Buy` is not Y

```
df.filter((df["Buy"] != "Y") | (df["Buy"].isNull()))
```

So if you want to filter where Buy and Sell are not 'Y' as it seems by what you've tried, you need to do this:

```
 df.filter((df["Buy"] != "Y") | (df["Buy"].isNull()) & (df["Sell"] != "Y") | (df["Sell"].isNull()))
```

Quick example:

**Input**

```
+---+----+----+
| id|Sell| Buy|
+---+----+----+
|  A|null|null|
|  B|   Y|   Y|
|  C|   Y|null|
|  D|   Y|null|
|  E|null|null|
+---+----+----+
```

Output

```
>>> df.filter((df["Buy"] != "Y") | (df["Buy"].isNull())).show(10)
+---+----+----+
| id|Sell| Buy|
+---+----+----+
|  A|null|null|
|  C|   Y|null|
|  D|   Y|null|
|  E|null|null|
+---+----+----+

>>> df.filter((df["Buy"] != "Y") | (df["Buy"].isNull()) & (df["Sell"] != "Y") | (df["Sell"].isNull())).show(10)
+---+----+----+
| id|Sell| Buy|
+---+----+----+
|  A|null|null|
|  E|null|null|
+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW, it worked for me when I added more brackets to separate conditions on sides of "&". I mean this:  df.filter(((df["Buy"] != "Y") | (df["Buy"].isNull())) & ((df["Sell"] != "Y") | (df["Sell"].isNull())))

Answer (score 2):

The easy and simple fix would be to use null safe operator

```
df.filter(~((df["Buy"].eqNullSafe("Y")) | (df["Sell"].eqNullSafe("Y"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Fill the null value first and do the filter.

```
df.na.fill('N') \
  .filter("Sell != 'Y' or Buy != 'Y'") \
  .show(10, False)

df.na.fill('N') \
  .filter("Sell != 'Y' and Buy != 'Y'") \
  .show(10, False)

+---+----+---+
|id |Sell|Buy|
+---+----+---+
|A  |N   |N  |
|C  |N   |Y  |
|D  |Y   |N  |
|E  |N   |N  |
+---+----+---+

+---+----+---+
|id |Sell|Buy|
+---+----+---+
|A  |N   |N  |
|E  |N   |N  |
+---+----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try with spark SQL by creating a temporary view and write queries naturally in SQL. Such as for this we can write

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('filter_value_not_equal_to_Y')
filterNotEqual=spark.sql("Select * from filter_value_not_equal_to_Y where Sell <>'Y' or Buy <>'Y'")
display(filterNotEqual)
```